# File downloaded with Google Drive API v3 has different content

Tags: c#, api, file, url, google-drive-api

I'm working with the Google Drive API for the very first time and I need to download a simple txt file that has as only content a single line with a version number (like 2.5.1.0), but when I download the file and open it, I get something totally different.

Also, if I just download the file using any browser, it has the expected content, but not when I download it through my application.

I would appreciate any advice on this.

This is my code so far:

```
private void CheckForUpdates()
    {
        GoogleDrive drive = new GoogleDrive();
        string url = drive.GetFileURL("current.txt");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

        string tmpPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "current.txt");
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        WebClient response = new WebClient();
        response.DownloadFile(url, tmpPath);
    }

public string GetFileURL(string fileName)
    {
        DriveService service = GetDriveService();
        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, properties, shared, webContentLink, webViewLink, fullFileExtension, capabilities)";
        listRequest.Q = string.Format("(name contains '{0}')", fileName);
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            string url = files[0].WebContentLink;
            string id = files[0].Id;                  
            return url;
        }
        return "";
    }


private DriveService GetDriveService()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
         DriveService service;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(_pathClave, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = _pathResult;
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        return service;
    }
```

This is the link: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3P8S21qYracclVaamM2Skp4bzA&export=download

Comment: "but when I download the file and open it, I get something totally different."   We're all really curious what you do get.

Comment: I cannot paste all the content of the file, it is too long.

Comment: aww. Not even a small clue what it might contain? A pastebin link?

Comment: have you find solution for this issue? currently, i am facing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Imports System.Net
        Imports System.ComponentModel

        Dim Str As IO.Stream
        Dim srRead As IO.StreamReader
        Dim NewVer As String = ""
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("WebContentLink")

        Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New IO.StreamReader(Str)
        NewVer = srRead.ReadToEnd.Trim
```

vb code worked good for me may help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your answer! If you believe that your code is helpful, please add some insights as to why this code works and what exactly it is supposed to work, thanks!